# Sendkeys Only Writing First Character from Text File

Tags: vba, fso

I'm trying to write everything from a text file, but it's only writing the first character.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Main
    Dim TextFile As Integer
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileContent As String

    'File Path of Text File
      FilePath = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Clipboard.txt"

    'Determine the next file number available for use by the FileOpen function
      TextFile = FreeFile

    'Open the text file
      Open FilePath For Input As TextFile

    'Store file content inside a variable
      FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)

    'Report Out Text File Contents
      SendKeys FileContent

    'Close Text File
      Close TextFile

End Sub
```

I've also tried this, but similarly only write the first character:

```
Sub Main
    Dim objFSO
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim objTextStream

    Const strFileName = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Clipboard.txt"
    Const fsoForReading = 1

    If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Clipboard.txt") Then
        'The file exists, so open it and output its contents
        Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, fsoForReading)
        SendKeys objTextStream.ReadAll
        objTextStream.close
        Set objTextStream = Nothing
    Else
        'The file did not exist
        SendKeys "was not found."
    End If

    'Clean up
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please help.  Thanks!

Comment: where is SendKeys sending the data ?

Comment: Tested both versions and they worked for me.

Comment: jstola, I've tried sending keys either to Word or Internet Explorer (neither works for me).  My end goal is to send it to Internet Explorer.

Comment: YowE3k, maybe I don't have the right reference libraries installed?

Comment: How are you calling this VBA macro while IE is the active application?  (No specific reference libraries should need to be loaded to run it - I only had the standard VBA, Excel Object, OLE Automation, and Office Object libraries loaded when I ran it in Excel.)

Comment: I'm using Nuance Dragon Naturally Speaking to run this script. Whether I call the macro from Word or IE, I get the same result.  I've written another script to open IE to the page I want, and then use the info from THIS script to paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I needed some more libraries before it would work.

I added Microsoft WMI Scripting Library, OLE Automation, VBA 6, and Visual Basic Runtime Objections. I'm not sure which one fixed it.